# Closing a form and then call another one

Tags: c#, forms, winforms

I want to close the current form I'm on (MainForm) and then opening a second one (Form).

I've tried:

```
private void buttonStartQuiz_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Close();

    Form2 form2 = new Form2();
    form2.ShowDialog();
}
```

Or adding the `this.Close();` after `form2.ShowDialog()` also doesn't work.

Any hints?

EDIT: Might as well add that by adding `this.Close()` after `form2.ShowDialog()` it close only when I close the new form.
If I choose `form2.Show()` instead it immediately closes both of the forms.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Change

```
this.Close();
```

To:

```
this.Hide();
```

Because you can't Close Main Application window and want to application runs after it.
You must hide main form or change main window to window who was still opened.

In this case you must close main window after `ShowDialog()` was ended.
Then you must add on the end of this button event function `this.Close()`

Your code new code is:

```
private void buttonStartQuiz_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // hide main form
        this.Hide();

        // show other form
        Form2 form2 = new Form2();
        form2.ShowDialog();

        // close application
        this.Close();
    }
```

Comment: But I do want to close it.

Although I guess that I could hide it, then when exiting form2 I could call it back?

Comment: @elvispt: Yes, you can do that. Change this.Close(); to this.Show();

Comment: What would be the correct way to call the hidden (main) from form2?

Comment: @elvispt: You can add to Form2() constructor, argument of type Form. You with this argument passing main window (this). And if you want from Form2 you can call this main window with Show funciton. You may change with this option ShowDialog() to Show() because hard to show form when he is blocked with ShowDialog() method.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand.

What am I supposed to do in the constructor?
public Form2(Form a) ?

How could I call the hidden form, let's say on the Form2_FormClosed event?

Comment: elvispt: I suggest going through some OOP tutorials (preferably in C#), because you clearly don't have a clue what he said :(

Comment: I don't understand the point of doing this: public Form2(Form form).

Comment: I managed to get it work. Although understand why is the problem.

Answer (score 6):

You can mess with ApplicationContext but the .NET framework already has very good support for this windowing mode with the WindowsFormsApplicationBase class.  Its ShutdownStyle property is available to let the program shut down only after the last window was closed.  Make the code in Program.cs look like this:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices;  // Add reference to Microsoft.VisualBasic!!

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1 {
  class Program : WindowsFormsApplicationBase {
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args) {
      var app = new Program();
      app.EnableVisualStyles = true;
      app.ShutdownStyle = ShutdownMode.AfterAllFormsClose;
      app.MainForm = new Form1();
      app.Run(args);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This works fine for me...

```
private void button_Name_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        form_2 Form2 = new Form2();
        Form2.ShowDialog();
        this.Close();
    }
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, it is better to explain the essential parts of the answer and possibly what was the problem with OPs code.

Answer (score 0):

```
Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
frm2.ShowDialog();
```

and

```
this.Close();
```

is not a good combination..

frm2 will actually load but you can't even see it because `this.Close();` will close every form just in a millisecond...

```
this.Hide();
```

works...

Answer (score 0):

Just enable or disable the form itself, instead of trying to close.

Code it like:

```
this.enabled = false;
```

in the click event or wherever you want it.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.Visible = false;
Form2 form2 = new Form2();
form2 .ShowDialog();
this.Close();
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: but this is the answer for his question
please try it before saying it is not working
his question was I want to close the current form I'm on (MainForm) and then opening a second one (Form).
and this is the answer for it

Comment: Mainly, you just need to tell what your code does, rather than just putting out lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace `this.Close()` with `this.Hide()`,
it will work perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
        Form1 f1 = new Form1();
        f1.Show();
    }
```

Is all you need

Answer (score -1):

You are closing the form first, you must load the 2nd form first.

```
private void buttonStartQuiz_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Form2 form2 = new Form2();
form2.ShowDialog();
this.Close();
}
```

Comment: Have you tested it ??

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
btCancel.FindForm().Close();
```

`btcancel` is a button that lays on the form you want to close.

Answer (score -1):

Put this in main form

```
private void mainform_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }
```

Worked for me.

Answer (score -2):

```
new play().Show();
this.Dispose();
```