# Close form without exit application

Tags: c#, windows

I'm currently working on a small project and would like some help on it.

I have 2 forms, the first is a login window and the second will be the main program. The problem I have is that when I close `form1` with `this.Close()` it is exiting the whole program.

I have a feeling that I need to use threading or something like that but I can't find the right resource for my problem to be solved.

Thanks.

Comment: Is this winforms or wpf? And it's not an issue of threading, but rather an issue of what "this" is in the scope that you're using it most likely. Code will help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Closing a form and then call another one.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2751076/closing-a-form-and-then-call-another-one)

Comment: I've not done a lot with winforms, but just to verify, you are creating your Login screen with the main window as it's parent, no?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could hide the first form instead of closing it:

```
this.Hide();
Form2 form2 = new Form2();
form2.Show();
```

Comment: Then I have another problem, when I close Form2 I would like to close the hidden Form1, how do I do that?

Comment: @Victor: Same way, but you're going to need to offer a way to genuinely close both forms and shut the app down.

Comment: Based on the fact that you hide the form, and will only close the app when you close this hidden form, which by the way, will be an unsused resource open the entire time.. I'd say this isn't the greatest solution...

Answer (score 3):

If you're using WPF, you can set [Application.MainWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.mainwindow.aspx) to your second "main" window, prior to closing your login form.

Comment: actually in vb.net you could specify the application shutdown mode. c# doesnt allow you to easily say. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/61b817f8-d7d3-44de-9095-91a6e3f2150c

Answer (score 3):

Can't you change your program.cs so that it runs the main form, and in the launch of the main form it creates and shows a login form and then hides itself (waiting for the login to happen to show itself)?

Comment: Exactly what I was gonna say:
Make sure you're not using the first form to load the application like this...

Application.Run(new Form1());

Answer (score 2):

Program.cs is where your main function is. If you created the project as a Windows App with Visual Studio then there will be a function in main that runs the form that opens when you start the program. Just get the login info from the login form in main and then call the second window. Here is an example:

```
[STAThread]
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //there's some other code here that initializes the program

    //Starts the first form (login form)
    Application.Run(new form1());

    //Get the login info here somehow. Maybe save in public members of form1 or
    // in a global utilities or global user class of some kind

    //Run the main program
    Application.Run(new mainProgramForm());
}
```

**EDIT: FORGOT SOMETHING**

I forgot to mention that if you do get members from the login form you will have to instantiate it first. This is not a good technique, and I recommend doing the Global user class idea over this, but I have a program that requires this method, and since I mentioned it, here is the example:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //there's some other code here that initializes the program

    //Instead of running a new form here, first create it and then run it
    Form1 form1 = new Form1();    //Creates the form
    Application.Run(form1);       //Runs the form. Program.cs will continue after the form closes

    //Get the login info
    string username = form1.Username;
    string password = form1.Password;

    //Get rid of form1 if you choose
    form1.Dispose();

    //Validate the user info

    //Run the main program
    Application.Run(new mainProgramForm());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

whats your opinion to create something like that

[image: tray Icon]

its called tray Icon

so user can `close all forms`  and the `app still running`,, and `user can go back to app any time`

lets start coding (note this is WPF Application)

```
private NotifyIcon m_notifyIcon;
private ContextMenuStrip m_contextMenu;
private bool _ForceClose;

public MainWindow()
{
     InitializeComponent();
     CreateNotifyIcon();

}

private void CreateNotifyIcon()
{
    m_contextMenu = new ContextMenuStrip();

    ToolStripMenuItem mI1 = new ToolStripMenuItem { Text = "Open" };
    mI1.Click += (sender, args) => Maximize();
    ToolStripMenuItem mI2 = new ToolStripMenuItem { Text = "Exit" };
    mI2.Click += (sender, args) => EndApplication();
    m_contextMenu.Items.Add(mI1);
    m_contextMenu.Items.Add(mI2);
    //Initalize Notify Icon
    m_notifyIcon = new NotifyIcon
    {
        Text = "Application Title",
        Icon = new Icon("Icon.ico"),
        //Associate the contextmenustrip with notify icon
        ContextMenuStrip = m_contextMenu,
        Visible = true
    };
}
```

and we have these functions

```
protected void Minimize()
{
    Hide();
}

protected void Maximize()
{
    Show();
    this.WindowState =WindowState.Normal;
}

protected void EndApplication()
{
    Minimize();
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    _ForceClose = true;
    WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
    this.Close();
    Environment.Exit(0);
}
```

and in `Window Closing` event listener (don't forget to add it)

```
private void Window_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (_ForceClose == false)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        Minimize();
    }
}
```

that's it, hope it help you

Answer (score 0):

Open Program.cs - you can do quite a bit before the call to Application run, including showing your login information.  Here is a sample from one of my projects.  It tries to find the database connection.  If it can't, it opens up a wizard and either connects to access or mssql.  If the open is good it shows a spalsh screen and finally runs the application, else it closes.

```
Application.EnableVisualStyles();
Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
DialogResult LclResult;

EESDatabasePersistentData LclPersist;
LclPersist = new EESDatabasePersistentData();
string LclDataType;
string LclDatabase;
string LclServer;
string Password;
string UserID;
if (!LclPersist.GetConnection(out LclServer, out LclDatabase, out LclDataType, out UserID, out Password))
{
        // Run the connection wizard
        GetConnection(out LclServer, out LclDatabase, out LclDataType, out UserID, out Password);
}


if (LclDataType == "ACCESS")
        InitDataAccess(LclDatabase);
else if (LclDataType == "SQLSERVER")
        InitDataSQL(LclServer, LclDatabase, UserID, Password);
if (OpenGood)
{
        if (!System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
        {
                FormSplash.Instance.SetupVersion();
                ///////////////////////////////////
                // If we don't call do events 
                // splash delays loading.
                Application.DoEvents();
                FormSplash.Instance.Show();
        }
        Application.DoEvents();

        Application.Run(new FormMentorMain());
}
else
        Application.Exit();
```