# Basic C# WinForms question about opening and closing other forms

Tags: c#, winforms

I have my code in `login.cs`:

```c#
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;

namespace Midnight_Serverpanel
{
    public partial class login : Form
    {
        public login()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    
        private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenStartForm();
        }

        private bool IsUserLoggedIn()
        {
            string tokenFilePath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "Google.Apis.Auth", "Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses.TokenResponse-user");
    
            try
            {
                if (File.Exists(tokenFilePath))
                {
                    // Überprüfen, ob die Datei einen gültigen Inhalt hat
                    string tokenContent = File.ReadAllText(tokenFilePath);

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tokenContent))
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Hier könntest du die Fehlermeldung protokollieren oder debuggen
                MessageBox.Show("Fehler beim Überprüfen des Tokens: " + ex.Message);
            }
    
            return false;
        }
    
        private void login_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (IsUserLoggedIn())
            {
                Program.UserLoggedIn = true;
                OpenStartForm();
            }
        }

        private void OpenStartForm()
        {
            try
            {
                Start sistema = new Start();
                sistema.Show();
                this.Hide();  // Close the current form
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Fehler beim Öffnen des Startformulars: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And all I want is when a usertoken is loaded that the login.cs would get skipped and start.cs gets opened right away. But all I get is that both windows get opened and I don't want to see that window with the "Login with Google" button.

My `Start.cs`:

```c#
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.Win32;
using Renci.SshNet;
using Renci.SshNet.Common;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Util;
//google

namespace Midnight_Serverpanel
{
    public partial class Start : Form
    {
        Liveserver u1;
        Devserver u2;
        Compilen u3;
    
        public Start()
        {
            u1 = new Liveserver();
            u2 = new Devserver();
            u3 = new Compilen();
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public class MultiTextWriter : TextWriter
        {
            private IEnumerable<TextWriter> writers;

            public MultiTextWriter(IEnumerable<TextWriter> writers)
            {
                this.writers = writers.ToList();
            }

            public MultiTextWriter(params TextWriter[] writers)
            {
                this.writers = writers;
            }
    
            public override void Write(char value)
            {
                foreach (var writer in writers)
                    writer.Write(value);
            }
    
            public override void Write(string value)
            {
                foreach (var writer in writers)
                    writer.Write(value);
            }
    
            public override void Flush()
            {
                foreach (var writer in writers)
                    writer.Flush();
            }
    
            public override void Close()
            {
                foreach (var writer in writers)
                    writer.Close();
            }
    
            public override Encoding Encoding
            {
                get { return Encoding.ASCII; }
            }
        }

        public class ControlWriter : TextWriter
        {
            private Control textbox;

            public ControlWriter(Control textbox)
            {
                this.textbox = textbox;
            }
    
            public override void Write(char value)
            {
                textbox.Text += value;
            }
    
            public override void Write(string value)
            {
                textbox.Text += value;
            }
    
            public override Encoding Encoding
            {
                get { return Encoding.ASCII; }
            }
        }
    
        private void toolStripMenuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.panel1.Controls.Clear();
            u2.Hide();
            u3.Hide();
            u1.Show();
            u1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            panel1.Controls.Add(u1);
        }

        private void toolStripMenuItem2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.panel1.Controls.Clear();
            u1.Hide();
            u3.Hide();
            u2.Show();
            u2.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            panel1.Controls.Add(u2);
        }

        private void toolStripMenuItem3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.panel1.Controls.Clear();
            u1.Hide();
            u2.Hide();
            u3.Show();
            u3.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            panel1.Controls.Add(u3);
        }
    
        private void toolStripMenuItem1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.panel1.Controls.Clear();
            u2.Hide();
            u3.Hide();
            u1.Show();
            u1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            panel1.Controls.Add(u1);
        }
    }
}
```

My `Program.cs`:

```c#
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Midnight_Serverpanel
{
    internal static class Program
    {
        public static bool OpenDetailFormOnClose { get; set; }
        public static bool UserLoggedIn { get; set; }  // Add a property to track user login status
        /// <summary>
        /// Der Haupteinstiegspunkt für die Anwendung.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
             Application.EnableVisualStyles();
             Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
             Application.Run(new login());
        }

        private static bool IsUserLoggedIn()
        {
            string tokenFilePath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "Google.Apis.Auth", "Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses.TokenResponse-user");
    
            try
            {
                if (File.Exists(tokenFilePath))
                {
                    // Überprüfen, ob die Datei einen gültigen Inhalt hat
                    string tokenContent = File.ReadAllText(tokenFilePath);

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tokenContent))
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Hier könntest du die Fehlermeldung protokollieren oder debuggen
                MessageBox.Show("Fehler beim Überprüfen des Tokens: " + ex.Message);
            }
    
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

I would really appreciate help, because this is my first ever application I ever written.

I would love some help and advice..

Comment: Your login form always is displayed, because your `Program.Main()` function always reaches the line `Application.Run(new login())`.

Comment: I would consider moving your logic that checks for token outside of login form like in a service and then show the form you want based on that result. You have IsUserLoggedIn function in 2 places. Put OpenStartForm in Program. Think of each class as person that does one thing and one thing only really well. Separation of concerns. :)

Comment: @GotStu: I don't know that I would describe that as a "service".  More likely "login controller".  But your overall advice is excellent, and the question code indeed makes a hash of the single responsibility principle.

Comment: IsUserLoggedIn ist now located at the login.cs
(https://pastebin.com/xVU2kRu3)
Program.cs (https://pastebin.com/r0xP9cWN) How to now open skip the one and open the other if verification is successfull? sorry if Im beeing dumb..

Comment: the program.cs has login instead of Start sorry

Comment: And I added the message box beforehand to debug my error but could proceed

Comment: @GotStu How to outsource that function properly? 
My current Start.cs (https://pastebin.com/Qh2WphUY)
My current login.cs (https://pastebin.com/7HBGEZRH)
My current program.cs (https://pastebin.com/sbNkPFby)

Comment: Here's an answer that addresses showing an initial login screen before going to the main window. It might be helpful for what you're trying to do: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74736871/5438626

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before start you app `Application.Run(new login());` you can make a decision about strategy for next actions.
First, you have to move your authentication logic to separated class and teach that to store tokens. As a result you'll get something like this

```
class LoginService {
    public bool IsUserLoggedIn(){...}
    public void SetToken(token){...}
    public string GetToken(){...}
}
```

Let's decide which form will be main form of your app, I think, it can be StartForm, run it with Application.Run(startForm);

Next, in StartForm make the service instance, or you can make it in Program.cs and pass to StartForm using constructor.
Before showing the StartForm, check service.IsuserLoggedIn();

If no, open LoginForm as a dialog `var result = loginForm.ShowDialog();`, in login form make sure that you set this.DialogResult before closing form, if your authorisation is successful set DialogResult.Ok, if no - set Cancel.

In StartupForm check the `result` variable, if it's Ok, try to read the token from the service. Next, if you have a token you can start work.

Answer (score 0):

A form, passed to `Application.Run` in Program.cs cannot be closed, if that form opened some other form(s). At least until that opened other forms will be closed.

But you can **hide** your Login form after showing Start form, by using suggested solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5548746/c-sharp-open-a-new-form-then-close-the-current-form):

```
public partial class LoginForm : Form
{
    // some stuff...
    private void MethodAfterUserLogIn()
    {
        this.Hide();
        var startForm = new StartForm();
        startForm.Closing += delegate { this.Close(); };
        startForm.Show();
    }
}
```

---

Another approach may help to avoid that dependency between Login form and Start form and based on @GotStu suggestion - separate logic and responsibility.

What Login form supposed to do? Allow user to input username/password probably. Allow press "Log in" or "Sign up" buttons probably. Should form by itself check user login status? I think not. I think, responsibility to check user login status should belong to class, which contains overall authorization-relevant logic.

For example, imagine some `AuthHelper` class with some relevant methods (very primitive):

```
internal class AuthHelper
{
    private static bool _isUserLoggedIn;

    internal static bool IsUserLoggedIn()
    {
        // User login status check logic...
        return _isUserLoggedIn; // result of login status check
    }
    internal static void LogIn(string username, string password)
    {
        // Log in logic...
        _isUserLoggedIn = true; // result of log in actions
    }
    internal static void LogOut(string username, string password)
    {
        // Log out logic...
        _isUserLoggedIn = false; // result of log our actions
    }
    internal static void SignUp(string username, string password)
    {
        // Sign up logic...
        // return? result of sign up actions
    }
}
```

Here you can see encapsulated (isolated, separated) logic, related only to user authentication. That class isn't responsible for nothing, except user auth, not dependent to Login form or any other form. How it can be used?

In your case, you have simple condition: *"if user logged in, then show Start form, elseway show Login form before"*. And you can transfer that condition directly into **Program.cs**. But in two ways:

```
public static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    public static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        if (!AuthHelper.IsUserLoggedIn())
           Application.Run(new LoginForm());
        if (AuthHelper.IsUserLoggedIn())
            Application.Run(new StartForm());
        // twice check because from here we don't know, 
        // was user logged in Login form or just cancelled (closed) it
    }
}
```

In Login form we perform log in/sign up actions for example. And instead of opening Start form (after successful authorization) we close Login form to allow application run now another (Start) form as main:

```
public partial class LoginForm : Form
{
    public LoginForm() => InitializeComponent();

    // Imagine that this is "Authorize"/"Log in" button
    private void Authorize_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AuthHelper.LogIn(tbUsername.Text, tbPassword.Text);
        // if (for any reason not logged in)
        // {
        //     MessageBox.Show(explain why)
        //     return; not Close here to allow user take another log in attempt
        // }

        // Means login action was successful and we can close form
        this.Close();
    }
    // Imagine that this is "Register"/"Sign up" button
    private void Register_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AuthHelper.SignUp(tbUsername.Text, tbPassword.Text);
        // After signing up user probably supposed to log in?
    }
}
```

LoginForm.cs, same to Program.cs, utilizes some `AuthHelper` and just passes data (username/password) to it, but not performing any actions over them by itself as it isn't form's responsibility.

Start form, same to Login form, supposed to contain some `Log out` call, also utilizing responsible for that action `AuthHelper` class. After logging out Start form supposed to be closed and application should be turned back to Login form. But I delegate resposibility to implement this to you)