# How to hide 2 forms at once?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 3 forms in my project:

- Login Form
- Dashboard Form
- Change Password Form

This is only a small project so there's nothing big of a feature that needs to be present. Anyways, The Login is the first Form that will appear. Once the user logs in, the Login Form hides and Dashboard appears. In the dashboard, there is a change password option that opens another form but it doesn't hide the Dashboard. If the user decides to change password, a messagebox will appear that basically says that the user successfully changed password and has an option whether to stay in Dashboard or go back to Login Form via MessageBoxButtons.YesNo.

This is the code that I went with:

Note that I'm in the Change Password Form.
Form2 is the Dashboard form.
Form1 is the Login form.

```
DialogResult dial = MessageBox.Show("Password successfully changed.\n\nDo you want to return to login page?", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
if (dial == DialogResult.Yes)
{
this.Hide();
Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
frm2.ShowDialog();
Hide();
Form1 frm1 = new Form1();
frm1.ShowDialog();
Close();
}
else if (dial == DialogResult.No)
this.Hide();
```

The `if (dial == DialogResult.Yes)` condition does not work. I'm trying to hide 2 forms at once (Change Password and Dashboard) and show Login Form. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Why is "you changed your password, do you want to carry on using the app or go back to the login screen so you can log in again before you carry on using the app?" even a question for the user?

Comment: Please stop accepting the default names for everything, such as Form1, Form2. You are allowed to, and really must get into the habit of, renaming everything to a sensible relevant name as you code. One day you will need to work with other developers (and that includes asking questions of people on the internet) who will have to figure out what all that obfuscated code means; it's incredibly hard to track code full of meaningless names

Comment: @flackoverstow sorry about that. I just really want to know how to hide 2 forms at once. This is just a project for myself to recall everything and learn new things, so my apologies for not naming the Forms properly.

Comment: No worries, but perhaps the most important and enduring lesson you will learn from this exercise is not actually about hiding forms (which you may or may not do ever again) but about writing good, clear, self documenting code that is easy for others to understand (starting with the most basic of all things:names) - that's something you'll do every day of your professional coding life ever more :)

Comment: As to hiding two forms at once; you just hide one then the other. It will happen so fast the user won't even be able to blink before they're both gone. Be careful with Show and ShowDialog; with ShowDialog the code effectively pauses at that point so no instructions after (like closing/hiding a form) will be processed until the Shown dialog is closed. Further, be careful creating new instances of forms when you may want to re-show an old instance

Comment: `this.Hide()` is the same as `Hide()`. And `Close()` also works on the current form. Is that really what you want?

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you named the forms, you'll thank yourself when you revisit this code in 6 months.

```
frmChangePassword frmCP = new frmChangePassword();
frmCP.ShowDialog();
DialogResult dial = MessageBox.Show("Password successfully changed.\n\nDo you want to return to login page?", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

if (dial == DialogResult.Yes)
{
// Hide this Dashboard
this.Hide();

// Instantiate frmLogin
frmLogin frmL = new frmLogin();

// Show the login form & force users to login successfully
frmL.ShowDialog();

//Confirm the login was success or quit the app if the user cancels, eg
if (frmL.Tag != "1")
{ 
  Application.Exit(); 
}

// Show the Dashboard again.
this.Show();
}
```

Comment: The form was currently in the change password, not the dashboard. There's a button in the dashboard that redirects me to the "change password" form. Once the user decides to change the password, then the messagebox will pop up. This code was made for the "dashboard" form.

Comment: @JeremyThomson Yeah but not with awful "not c# naming convention camelCase Hungarian like frmLogin" names. Forms are classes; in C# the convention is NamesLikeThis for classes, and in windows forms generally it's suffixed with form, e.g LoginForm, MainForm, ChangePasswordForm

Comment: Also, why the two approaches of "use DialogResult to determine the result of the dialog" and "use a string in the Tag to determine the result of the dialog"? Why not make consistent?

Answer (score 0):

Showing any form prior to making the main form visible can be tricky business because that first form will try to become the main application window (i.e. `Application.OpenForms[0]`) which is pathological. I have answers explaining this for [Login Form](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74736871/5438626) and [Splash Screen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75534137/5438626).

What I want to do is adapt that first answer to your situation where a mock flow would be:

**Login**

[image: login]

---

**Dashboard (main application window)**

[image: dashboard]

---

**Simulated change password (new)**

[image: change password]

---

To answer your question "hide two forms at once" first look at the response to `MessageBox.Yes`. It's going to take that response and make it the `DialogResult` of the change password form which closes both the message box and the change password form (with dashboard still to be hidden below).

```
public partial class ChangePasswordForm : Form
{
    public ChangePasswordForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        buttonOK.Click += (sender, e) =>
        {
            switch (MessageBox.Show(
                this,
                "Return to Login Screen?",
                "Login Successful!",
                MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
                MessageBoxIcon.Question))
            {
                // Close THIS form by copying the MessageBox result
                case DialogResult.Yes:  DialogResult = DialogResult.Yes;  break;
                case DialogResult.No:  DialogResult = DialogResult.No;  break;
            }
        };
        buttonCancel.Click += (sender, e) => DialogResult = DialogResult.No;
    }
}
```

---

Meanwhile, the `DashboardForm` has been waiting for the dialog result of the `ChangePasswordForm` in the response to clicking the [Change Password] button.

```
public partial class DashboardForm : Form
{
    public DashboardForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // Ordinarily we don't get the handle until
        // window is shown. But we want it now.
        _ = Handle;
        // Call BeginInvoke on the new handle so as not to block the CTor.
        BeginInvoke(new Action(() => execLoginFlow()));
        // Ensure final disposal of modal forms. Failure to 
        // dispose of window handles can cause exit hangs.
        Disposed += (sender, e) =>
        {
            _loginForm.Dispose();
            _changePasswordForm.Dispose();
        };
        buttonSignOut.Click += (sender, e) => IsLoggedIn = false;
        buttonChangePassword.Click += (sender, e) =>
        {
            switch (_changePasswordForm.ShowDialog(this))
            {
                case DialogResult.Yes: IsLoggedIn = false; break;
                case DialogResult.No: /* N O O P */ break;
            }
        };
    }
```

This in turn changes the `IsLoggedIn` bool which controls the visibility of the `Dashboard`, giving you the behavior you describe.

```
    bool _isLoggedIn = false;
    public bool IsLoggedIn
    {
        get => _isLoggedIn;
        set
        {
            if (!Equals(_isLoggedIn, value))
            {
                _isLoggedIn = value;
                OnIsLoggedInChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    protected virtual void OnIsLoggedInChanged()
    {
        if (IsLoggedIn)
        {
            WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
            Text = $"DASHBOARD - Welcome {_loginForm.UserName}";
            Visible = true;
        }
        else execLoginFlow();
    }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Comment: [Clone](https://github.com/IVSoftware/login-options.git)