Best approach for displaying license activation dialog
I have a text editor, now I'm implementing licensing support. Licenses are managed on a third-party server (SAAS).
Desired Flow

The user opens the editor.
If they have no license (first-time open):

An activation dialog pops up saying that they have no license and need to activate. It has three options: Online activation, Offline activation and Request a 14-day trial. Let's focus on the trial for now as it's the easiest.
When they select Request Trial and click Next, a request to the licensing API is fired and a Success dialog displays with their serial number (0 for trial), license key and the Start Working (OK) button.
When the Start Working button is clicked, the main form is shown.


If they already have a license and it's trial, I would like to pop up a message once a day saying something like "You have 5 days remaining in your trial, please consider upgrading", maybe with an Upgrade button straight away. Upon dismissing this message, the main form opens.
If they have a fully activated license, the main form opens.

The main form can also show a dialog that allows to select document type to create. It happens if a corresponding setting is on (turned on by default).
What I Tried
conditional Application.Run()
The first thing that came to my mind was calling Application.Run() inside an if condition: if there is no license, run with activation dialog, else show main form. An excerpt of program.cs:
    var license = TryFetchCurrentLicense();

    if (license is null) {
        Log.Warning("License not found.");

        Application.Run(new ActivationDialog());
    }
    Application.Run(new MainWindow());

And in my ActivationResultDialog form I have:
    private void OkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        var mainWindow = new MainWindow();
        mainWindow.Show();
        this.Close();
    }

That lead to an interesting effect: the main form was shown twice, i.e., after clicking the OK button in the ActivationResultDialog, I got Select Document Type, then, when submitting it, I got it another time. The select document type dialog opens on load of the main form:
private void MainWindow_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (Config.General.AfterStart == ActionAfterStart.SelectNewDocumentType) {
        ShowSelectForm();
    }
}

The ShowSelectForm() method does several things, the most important one is opening a dialog and then spawning a new MDI child window.
On Load or On Shown of the Main Form
If I move the license checking logic into the MainWindow_Load() event, it leads to weird issues like not spawning of the MDI child. If however I move the ShowSelectForm() logic to the MainWindow_Shown() event, I'm getting double main window again.
The Question
What would be the best approach? I feel something is deeply wrong with calling MainWindow.Show() at the end of the flow. What is a better and saner alternative?
I was also considering decoupling the whole license logic into a separate executable, like activator.exe, and then using named pipes to transfer data. However, how would I prevent the user from seeing and using the main form while they do their activation dance? It seems, I lack some understanding here.

Review your license null check. In case of null you display ActivationDialog, but you don't return on next step, so it goes to display MainWindow whenever ActivationDialog is closed. You probably want put MainWindow under else statement there or append return after Application.Run(new ActivationDialog());

When you call this.Close(); in OkButton_Click, you close the starting Form, which closes the application (Application.Run([Some Form]) sets the AppContext's MainForm). After that, as mentioned in the previous comment, you get to Application.Run(new MainWindow()); -- At that point, you have already created a instance of mainWindow, and shown it; if it creates a Dialog (which runs a message loop on its own), you get more trouble you care about --  You could show the activation dialog from MainForm itself, then close everything if the licensing procedure doesn't go through

You can check simplified fiddle to see the behaviour on simple strings and see solutions as well.

@Auditive Thank you. If I add return, then, when the license check passes, the main form opens with the dialog, but when I select document type, the app silently closes.

These might be helpful. 1. For the general case of showing "any" form (like a dynamic splash) before showing main form: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75534137/5438626 2. For a login splash that pretty much addresses this exact scenario https://stackoverflow.com/a/74736871/5438626.
