# Ways to quit application after launching multiple winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms

Let's say I launched multiples winforms from Program.cs with

```
Form1 form1 = new Form1();
form1.show();
Form2 form2 = new Form2();
form2.show();
Application.Run();
```

How do I quit application when all forms are closed by User ?

I can of course put Application.Exit() in FormClosed event but it's not very elegant I think. Are there other ways ?

Update: I mean it's not elegant to hard code each FormClosed each I have to add a new form. So is there a way I can HOOK ANY FormClosed event globally so that I can maintain the code in a central event handler without doing the PLUMBING BY HAND.

In some frameworks like Wordpress you can capture any event for any object globally I want the same kind of thing.

Comment: What's so "inelegant" about exiting the application when a form is closed if that's what you want to happen?

Comment: Inherit from `ApplicationContext` - see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13406508/111794).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Application.Exit() is required in this case.  Another approach is that you designate one of the forms as the "main window".  And the app will terminate when it is closed:

```
 Application.Run(form1);
```

The .NET framework also supports a "when last window closes" shutdown mode.  Check my code in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2751076/closing-a-form-and-then-call-another-one/2751234#2751234) for the required code.

Comment: I already mentionned Application.Exit is required. My problem is about how it is possible to hook the FormClosed Event globally so that I don't have maintenance hassle by doing the plumbing by hand each time I will add a new form class.

Comment: I read your other thread and learned about ShutdownMode.AfterAllFormsClose that should solve my problem thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use Application.OpenForms to process all open forms and decide what to do with them. If you know which one should be saved - prompt the user, otherwise close it. And so on.

Answer (score 1):

You can maintain a List of the forms that are open, and, each time a form is closed have it delete itself from that list and then check if the list is empty. If the list is empty, end the application.