# Create a new form every time a button has been clicked

Tags: c#, winforms

i was wondering. How does the applications such as Microsoft Word, Excel etc, create a new form with blank inside it, it is like we create another new form.

I tried the code:

```
this.Hide();

Form2 secondaryForm = new Form2(); 
secondaryForm.ShowDialog();

this.Close();
```

The above code is to create a new blank form (new form), but that is limited time only. What i was wondering is, how does the applications can make a thousand new blank form (new form) in such a unlimited time?

Note: what i mean by **Unlimited time** is: we can create a new form, the form will always be created, no matter how many times we are click the "new" button

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by `unlimited time`?

Comment: i mean, when i click the "button" (which is create a new form), the new form will always be created, no matter how many times we are click the "button"

Comment: Call Show, not ShowDialog and don't close the parent form

Comment: @Fuhans use `secondaryForm.Show()` instead of `ShowDialog()` and do not close your primary form

Comment: you can try `while(true)new Form2().Show();`, should do what you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the answer above me are good, but i want to expand them.

the reason that your code isn't working is because you are closing the **main form**

main form is the form you run when the program start. if you create a simple winform and look at the `main` function you'll see something like

```
     Application.EnableVisualStyles();
     Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
     Application.Run(new Form1());
```

and when you close the Form1 you are coming back to here and continue to run, finish the main function and end the program.

what you can do, on top of what everyone else suggested, is creating a main form that not visible, and create another form right after the creation of the main form. in this way you'll be able to close and open forms as you'd like and that won't close the program.

as for what you've asked, to be able to open several forms. that you can do simply be doing:

```
Form frm = new Form();// Creating a form
frm.Show();// displaying the form
```

the `ShowDialog` method does what `show` does, but also freeze the form that opened it. so you don't want it probably

Comment: Hmm yeah, didn't think about that setting being the default. But there is a better solution than the one you propose, just [change the ShutdownMode to AfterAllFormsClose](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2751234/366904).

Comment: @CodyGray omg! thank you! that's awesome. never though there is such a think. wow... i just think of all the times i could have used it...

Comment: It is a built-in option on the Properties page for VB.NET apps. I'm not sure why it's so well hidden in C#.

Answer (score 0):

Following code will allow you to open any number of forms without closing the main form.

```
//this.Hide();

Form2 secondaryForm = new Form2(); 
secondaryForm.Show();

//this.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

It is simple, they just create a new instance of the desired form class and call its [`Show` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.show.aspx):

```
MyForm frm = new MyForm();
frm.Show();
```

You're currently using the `ShowDialog` method, which creates a *modal* dialog—i.e. one that blocks user interaction with the rest of your application until the user dismisses it. That is not what you want.

You also don't need to call the `Hide` and `Close` methods unless you actually want to close the original form. The Office applications do not do this—"New" simply opens a new window, leaving the current one intact.

If you *do* want to close the original form when opening a new one, do it like this:

```
// Create and display new form
MyForm frm = new MyForm();
frm.Show();

// Close this form
this.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to `produce` forms once we click on the button, the forms should be produced and shown **regardless of the limit to the number of forms**. You can use a `Timer` for this purpose:

```
//Place this code in your main form constructor
Timer t = new Timer {Interval = 100};    
t.Tick += (s,e) => {
   new Form2().ShowDialog();
};
button1.Click += (s,e) => {
   t.Start();
};
//NOTE: you have to use the stop button of the IDE to stop this,
//it will run continuously producing new forms and showing them 
//without allowing you to touch the Close button of your main form.
```

You should limit the number of forms because we can't produce as many forms as possible, I've tested and there was an `StackOverflowException` thrown in `System.dll` with 272 forms opened :))). Try adding a `count` variable and stop the timer when it reaches a number for example a 272)